# query with rt:activeUser -google analytics-

Tags: analytics, klipfolio

I need to see in the query explorer (google analytics) a query for use in dashboard with active users rt:activeUsers for use in dashboard klipfolio  and 
I do not know how because only see ga: not rt:; any idea is appreciated 
tks a lot
R.

Answer (score 1):

RT is only available in Google Analytics Realtime API, it's using a different API than what Klipfolio natively plugs into.

You need an intermediate stage, where you fetch the API token and then query the Google Analytics RT API.